# Range.sort 0 should come first

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to sort the column through VBA:

```
Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

My data is like :

```
60630
9277
10470
3300
83677
251960
7982
0
2000
6000
267942
17825
0
```

Output:

```
2000
3300
6000
7982
9277
10470
17825
60630
83677
251960
267942
0
0
```

I want `0` to be first in resultant data set, is there any property in sort option could do that?

Comment: This code does sort the `0`s to the top when I run it.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried and tested the following and it works as you expected, as Peh mentioned if your cells have a leading apostrophe (') then the following will remove that apostrophe and then sort:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim c As Range
Set Rng = ws.Range("B2", ws.Range("B2").End(xlDown))

For Each c In Rng
    If Not c.HasFormula Then
        c.Formula = c.Value
    End If
Next

ws.Range("B2", ws.Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a good idea to fully qualify the ranges, but that cannot be the issue because as you see from the OPs input/output that sorting happens in that range, so Excel must have guessed the correct sheet.

Comment: @Peh you are right, as usual,.. Updated my answer to reflect your comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mind losing any formula, then you can use:

```
With Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Value = .Value
    .Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided does exactly what you want. It sorts the `0`s to the top when I run it.

But you have to make sure that all are numbers. If the `0` are formatted as text like with an apostrophe `'0` then they will be sorted at the end.

Note that you won't see that apostrophe until you edit this specific cell.